# Solve the system using elimination What are a, b, and c in the quadratic equation, ax^2+bx+c=y given the

Tags: differential-equations, linear-algebra, algebraic-manipulation, algebra, ncalgebra

Solve the system using elimination What are a, b, and c in the quadratic equation, ax^2+bx+c=y given the points: (2,17), (-2,9), and (1,6), please solve the question using steps e.g. (step 1, step 2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to solve this step by step using elimination:

First we solve for a and eliminate a:

```
sol1 = Solve[eqs[[1]], a, Reals][[1]]
eqs1 = eqs[[2 ;; 3]] /. sol1 // Simplify
```

[image]

Then we solve the new equations for b and eliminate b:

```
sol2 = Solve[eqs1[[1]], b][[1]]
eqs2 = eqs1[[2]] /. sol2
```

[image]

Finally we solve for a and use our results backwards to get a:

```
sol3 = Solve[eqs2, c][[1]]
sol1 /. sol2 /. sol3
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Solve[Table[
  a*x^2 + b*x + c == y /. 
   Thread[{x, y} -> i], {i, {{2, 17}, {-2, 9}, {1, 6}}}], {a, b, c}]
(* {{a -> 3, b -> 2, c -> 1}} *)
```